# How to update data in RecycleView in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have read from kivy that RecycleView is able to update data by calling `refresh_from_data()` manually after data is changed. I still have a few questions.

Here is my code. I tried to simplified it as the original one is pretty long.

In .py,

```
class FilterPage(Screen):
    def call_DB(self, price_min, price_max):
        'codes and shits'
        'Basically, I filter some result according to users input'
        'and store it in a list called real_result'
        'I want to update content and length of real_result for RecycleView'

        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.rv = self.app.rv
        self.rv.refresh_from_data()

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global real_result
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(len(real_result))]

kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")
class MyApp(App):    
    rv = RV()
    def build(self):
        return kv

MyApp().run()
```

In .kv,

```
<ProductButton>:
    on_release: print("success")
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'ProductButton'    
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
        spacing: 10

<ProductPage>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: "dot01.png"
            size: root.width, root.height
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RV:
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
```

1. Any limitation on the format of data to be updated?
   I read this, https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/uix/recycleview.html. Should I also include this part of code in my RecycleView class?

```
def refresh_from_data(self, *largs, **kwargs):
    self._refresh_flags['data'].append(kwargs)
    self._refresh_trigger()
```

2. I just want to update content in real_result and its length. Can it be done by calling `refresh_from_data()`? Should I pass any variables when calling it?
3. I want to include a few pieces of information in self.data. How?

The question is a bit long and I have cut many codes. If you need more details, please comment below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To change the content you only need to change the included data. No need to do anything additional.

```
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global real_result
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(len(real_result))]

    def alter_data(self):
        self.data = [{'text': str(x+x)} for x in range(len(real_result))]
```

and then call alter_data

In my code I use:

```
def refresh_data(self):
    self.data = []
    records_new = self.PW.dbcon.session.query ...

    for n_rows in records_new:
        r_tab_name = n_rows.tab_name
        d={'t_col1': r_tab_name.c1
            , 't_col2': r_tab_name.c2
            , 's_col3': r_tab_name.s3 if r_tab_name.s3 is not None else 0
            }

        self.data.append(d)
    self.data_for_thz=self.data
```

kv:

```
<LocalRecyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:

            Label:
            Button:
            Button:
            ...


<MyClass>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            ...
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'LocalRecyWidget'
            id: ....
            data: root.data_for_thz
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                ...
```

Comment: I tried to call alter_data() after self.rv.refresh_from_data() but fail. I printed the length of real_result in alter_data() and it showed correct length. But RV showed nothing. Am I call the function in a wrong place?

Comment: I guess that refresh_from_data()  is called when data changes. So you have to change the data in a different call.

Comment: Do you mean that maybe I should try update data within RecycleView so that I can do something similar to yours?

Comment: When you change the data the view is refreshed automatically I think